# Make border fade in/out on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there an easy way to fade a CSS `border-bottom` onto my image on hover, and have said border fade out again when not hovered anymore?

```
<div class="hover">
<img src="images/ex.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use JQUERY for this

In your CSS Style sheet, make this entry.

```
div.hover {
      border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);

      transition: border-color 1s linear;
      -moz-transition: border-color 1s linear;    /* FF3.7+ */
      -o-transition: border-color 1s linear;      /* Opera 10.5 */
      -webkit-transition: border-color 1s linear; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    }

    div.hover:hover {
      border-color: rgba(1,1,1,1);
    }
```

[CLICK HERE---------->Check my JSFIDDLE to see how it works.<----------CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/y2A7B/)

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want it to fade slowly in :P

Comment: @user2328659 see my answer for it to "fade in slowly" the `1s` is the speed of the transition you can change that to your will

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML Code:

```
<div class="hover">
    <img src="images/ex.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Your Jquery Code:

```
$(function(){
  $(".hover").hover(
      function(){
          $(this).css({'border-bottom':'1px solid #888', opacity: '0.8'}); 
      },
      function(){
          $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none'); 
      }
  );                             
});
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not fading in? o.O What shall I add for it to fade?

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.hover {
    border-bottom:none;
    transition: border-bottom 1s;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom 1s;
{

.hover:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #888;
}
```

This would work more fluently over the Javascript method

Answer (score 0):

```
 div.mosueover{
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(50,50,50,1);

  transition: /*all*/ border-color 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: /*all*/ border-color 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: /*all*/ border-color 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: /*all*/ border-color 1s ease-in-out;
}

div.mosueover:hover {
  border-color: rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
}
```