# JQuery: FadeIn an addclass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came to the point that I have to ask this to the community.
I have this site at the moment:
http://gyazo.com/e8f8e9884c3d40dee003c2234c840d56

As you can see in the menubar, the Home has a border underneath it.
What I'm trying to accomplish **with JQuery** is that whenever I hover any other menu item, the border will fadein slowly, and when the mouse leaves it will fadeout.

My current JQuery code:

```
$("li").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow').addClass("current");
    });
    $("li").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass("current", 600);
    });
```

The current class is the class that adds the border.

Anyone got some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make border fade in/out on hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685421/make-border-fade-in-out-on-hover)

Comment: No, that is using CSS. I want to use JQuery for this function.

Comment: Then use the css for the transition class, and then add the class with jQuery. Still the same thing. And `.hover()` is probably the jquery method you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use css `transitions` instead

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 2s ease;
}
ul li:hover {
  border-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can not pass two parameters to 'removeClass' function in jquery.

you can check their documentation on 'removeClass'. If you want to remove multiple classes you have to send it in one parameter using spaces between each className.

and if you want to remove the class after the fadein effect completes, then just call the removeClass function in its call back. ( for reference read the documentation of fadein https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ )

```
 $("li").mouseenter(function(){
var self = this;
            $(self).fadeIn('slow',function() {
self.addClass('current');
});
        });
        $("li").mouseleave(function(){
           var self = this;
            $(self).fadeOut('slow',function() {
self.removeClass('current');
});
        });
        });
```

or if you want that after a certain time ,let us assume that 1000ms/1sec then the code will be:

```
$("li").mouseenter(function(){
    var self = this;
                $(self).fadeIn(1000,function() {
    self.addClass('current');
    });
            });
            $("li").mouseleave(function(){
               var self = this;
                $(self).fadeOut(1000,function() {
    self.removeClass('current');
    });
            });
            });
```

Comment: I have not given you the final code so that you will put that and that will execute according to your scenario. because you have not given the html and css code. give me that then only I can give you the  final code.

I have given you the idea so that you can apply in your code.

Comment: I have to tried to show you the major mistakes you have done in your jquery code.